# DC motor - selection

Tags: motor, dc

I'm not an electrical engineer . I would like to know whether a normal DC motor will hold the load when the power is turned off?? Or should I need to install a controller to hold the load at that position if so what kind of controller I need to install . Please help me out??

Comment: for what application and how strong the DC motor must hold its position? there are several solutions, depend on the application. Alternatively, you can use servo/stepper DC motor that has 'built in' holding function

Comment: I'm planning for a Push load application and the payload of my system is 50Kg. We are not going for a servo or a stepper motor as it would cost high . planning for proto model with a simple DC motor

Comment: OK, for 50kg load, if the radius is 10 cm, the torque is 500 kgcm or 434 lb-in. Maybe this motor suitable: http://www.dumoremotors.com/dp500-inline-gear-motors.html There is option for an electro mechanical brake.

Answer (score 1):

The motor itself will not hold the load. You may need to transfer shaft power to a worm gearbox, or you may install a electromechanical brake/clutch.
It depends on your application, maybe a better description would help.

Answer (score 0):

When power is disconnected entirely from a brushed DC motor the shaft will spin freely. If you want to lock the shaft in place then you should tie the two connections together. This will cause any motion to generate EMF in the wires that will cause the motor to oppose said motion.

Comment: That won't lock it in place, it'll just make it harder to turn.

Comment: It also will only have an effect on a permanent magnet DC motor.  For a shunt wound motor, no field = no CEMF.  And anyway, it won't hold a load, you will still need a brake.